# how do i set my authentication backend as default in settings.py file of my django project(Extended AbstractBaseUser model)

Tags: python, django, django-authentication, django-users, django-auth-models

I have written the following class for Auth Back end and placed it inside a file "authentication.py" inside the app directory:

```
from events.models import User

class authBackend():
    def authenticate(self, request, username, passwprd):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(rollNo=username)
            success = user.check_password(password)
            if success:
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return None

    def get_user(self, uid):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=Uid)
        except:
            return None
```

then i added (or at least i thought i did) it to settings.py:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'events.authentication'
]
```

this is how i am logging in the user:

```
def login_view(request):
    if request.method == "POST":

        # Attempt to sign user in
        rollno = request.POST["rollno"]
        password = request.POST["password"]

        user = authenticate(request, username=rollno, password=password)

        # Check if authentication successful
        if user is not None:
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("events:index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "events/login.html", {
                "message": "Invalid roll number and/or password."
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "events/login.html")
```

But i am getting the following trace back:

> ImportError at /login Module "events" does not define a "authentication" attribute/class

I am a noob and i am pretty sure i am doing something wrong, i just don't understand what it is.

Can someone please tell me how to do it right?

Comment: It should be `'events.authentication.authBackend'`

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Thank you for your reply, yeah, i realized i need to import the class not the file, but can you please check if there's something wrong with my Back end and my login_view?

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar: it probably is better to start with the `BaseBackend`, or even the `ModelBackend`, since the backend should also implement `get_user_permissions`, `get_group_permissions`, `get_all_permissions` and `has_perms`.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Actually, i am unable to log in any user, it just returns None

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar: you also made a typo in the parameter names: it is `password`, not `passwprd`

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem sorry about the typo, i had already corrected that in my original code

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar all of the above plus the backend shouldn't directly import the user model (it should be reusable) you should use [`django.contrib.auth.get_user_model`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) to get the user model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to import it with the class name as well, so:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
    'events.authentication.authBackend'
]
```

In your `authBackend`, you also made a number of mistakes. First of all the authentication backend [needs to implement a number of functions [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends):

> The user model and its manager will delegate permission lookup functions (`get_user_permissions()`, `get_group_permissions()`, `get_all_permissions()`, `has_perm()`, `has_module_perms()`, and `with_perm()`) to any authentication backend that implements these functions.

You thus will need to implement this functions as well. Therefore it might be better to inherit from the [**`BaseBackend`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.BaseBackend) or perhaps even better from the [**`ModelBackend`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.backends.BaseBackend), since that will already implement the logic, and you thus only need to override certain functions to let it work with your new model.

You also made a typo in the parameter names: it is `password`, not <s>`passwprd`</s>:

```
from django.contrib.auth.backends import BaseBackend
from events.models import User

class authBackend(BaseBackend):
    def authenticate(self, request, username, password):
        try:
            user = User.objects.get(rollNo=username)
            success = user.check_password(password)
            if success:
                return user
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            pass
        return None

    def get_user(self, uid):
        try:
            return User.objects.get(pk=Uid)
        except:
            return None
```

---

> **Note**: According to the [*PEP-8 Style guide* [pep-0008]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#class-names),
> class names are written in *PerlCase* starting with an uppercase, so you might want to consider renaming
> <s>`authBackend`</s> to `AuthBackend`.

Comment: I am still unable to login users using the login_view, there are two things i think are going wrong here, one is that i probably need to import the authenticate function in my views as well, and second is, i probably did something wrong with implementing the back end(sorry if it seems like a stupid question i am a beginner)

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar: you did not import the authenticate function in your view?

Comment: "from events.authentication import authBackend" and while using "user = authBackend.authenticate(request, username=rollno, password=password)"  Is this the correct way to do it?

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar: no, the idea is that you have a loose coupling with the backend, so `from django.contrib.auth import authenticate`. Furthermore that would not work at all, since `request` is then passed to the `self` parameter.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i imported it that way. I am giving the correct values of "rollNo" field and the "password" field, but authenticate still returns None. https://pastebin.com/abvhhu2Z this is my User model, is there something wrong there?

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar: the password is hashed in the database? Did you fix the typo in the `password` parameter?

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar in `create_superuser` you don't set the password properly. Do it similar to how you do in `create_user`

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar: you should use `.set_password` to make sure that the password is properly hashed.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, nope it's not working. I can register a new user, i can check that the user has been created using the shell, but i can't authenticate and login the user. I am stuck

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar: but does your *database* contains the *hashed* passwords, or the *raw* passwords...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it still contains the raw passwords. I used set_password while creating the user in my register view: "user = User.objects.create_user(email, username, year, branch, rollno, password)
            user.set_password(user.password)
            user.save()"

Comment: @ApoorvaShridhar: but normally the `create_user` will hash these, so you should not use `user.set_password(user.password)`, since then you are hashing a *second* time.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes now it's showing hashed passwords. But do i also need to re write the login method? https://pastebin.com/DMyqKEez This is my login view basically"login(request, user)". It's now redirecting to the "success_url" as it should, nor is it giving me the error message, so that means that authenticate method is working. But the user is still not logged in. Do i need to re implement "login" as well?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I can't login to django admin interface either

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i resolved the issue. Thank you very much, you have been a huge help, thanks